# limit values from RegionPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, regions, webmathematica

I want to find the limit value (range) of "x", "y" and "z" on which above above function is positive for given range.
for this i use

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 - y + z - x y z < 0, {x, 1, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, 1, 10}]
```

where `f[x_ ,y_ ,z_]:= x^2 - y + z - x * y * z`

now how to find the limit value of x,y,z from this plot???
any other method???

See
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ23M.png

Answer (score 1):

This answers the question of how to get "limit values from RegionPlot3D?"

```
RegionBounds@ DiscretizeGraphics@ RegionPlot3D[x^2 - y + z - x y z < 0,
    {x, 1, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, 1, 10}]
(*  {{1., 10.}, {0.613142, 10.}, {1., 10.}}  *)
```

Of course, `RegionPlot3D` makes a rough, discrete approximation to the actual region, so some numerical error is present.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows.

```
Maximize[y, x^2 - y + z - x y z < 0 && x >= 1 && x <= 10 && y >= -10 && y <= 10 &&z >= 1 && z <= 10, {x, y, z}]
```

> {10, {x -> 6, y -> 10, z -> 6}}

```
Minimize[y,x^2 - y + z - x y z < 0 && x >= 1 && x <= 10 && y >= -10 && y <= 10 &&   z >= 1 && z <= 10, {x, y, z}]
```

> {1/50 (-1 + Sqrt[1001]), {x -> 
>      1/10 (-1 + Sqrt[1001]) - 
>       Sqrt[-10 + 1/50 (-1 + Sqrt[1001]) + 1/100 (-1 + Sqrt[1001])^2], 
>     y -> 1/50 (-1 + Sqrt[1001]), 
>     z -> (1/50 (1 - Sqrt[1001]) + (1/10 (-1 + Sqrt[1001]) - 
>         Sqrt[-10 + 1/50 (-1 + Sqrt[1001]) + 
>          1/100 (-1 + Sqrt[1001])^2])^2)/(-1 + 
>       1/50 (-1 + Sqrt[1001]) (1/10 (-1 + Sqrt[1001]) - 
>          Sqrt[-10 + 1/50 (-1 + Sqrt[1001]) + 
>           1/100 (-1 + Sqrt[1001])^2]))}}

The bounds of $x$ and $z$ can be found similarly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Maximize[y, x^2 - y + z - x y z < 0 && x >= 1 && x <= 10 && y >= -10 && y <= 10 &&z >= 1 && z <= 10, {x, y, z}]
```

and

```
Minimize[y, x^2 - y + z - x y z < 0 && x >= 1 && x <= 10 && y >= -10 && y <= 10 &&z >= 1 && z <= 10, {x, y, z}]
```

is not the range but the boundary value (upper/lower) and is not the complete limit range.

Comment: @ Steve: Can you base your statement? Of course, by optimization the end points of the ranges under consideration  are obtained.

Comment: any other method??

Comment: @ Steve. Sorry, don't understand you. I will be waiting for a reply.